# Displaying no Data label when data not available for a series group in Column chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, graph, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have 5 entities: a,b,c,d,e each displaying values for 3 years (year1, year2 and year 3)

The graph is a column graph. The problem is that I need to display No data label when values for years are not present for entities.

I used the no data label property but it only displays the no data label when data is not present for entire chart and not the way I wanted

(My Graph displays Entities as category groups and Years as series group -row index with label as Years)

Here is the link to whats happening right now: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx_Po7ND9VtON0J2ZERSSHl2OVE

Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: Can you share dataset or a data example. Do you want to display "No Data"  as label or what do you want to display for no data present?

Comment: Thanks for replying to my comments.. I decided to create 5 small graphs with x axis removed for them and added a line (acting as X axis). And I was able to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying to my comments. I decided to create 5 small graphs with x axis removed for them and added a line (acting as X axis). And I was able to achieve what I wanted